# pass in vue data into a component but I have other props too

Tags: javascript, vue.js, prop

I have data in App.vue that looks like this:

```
data() {
    return {
        information: {
          item1: 'item 1 string',
          item2: 'item 2 string', 
          item3: 'item 3 string'
        } 
    }
},
```

I want to pass this info into a component like this:

`<ComponentName prop="something-else" info=this.data.information.item1 />`

But I don't get the data, I just get the string..?

[Passing data to components in vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534151/passing-data-to-components-in-vue-js)

SO I go:

`<ComponentName prop="something-else" :info=this.data.information.item1>`

But my whole page goes blank

[Vue JS 3: How to pass data from one component to another other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68225444/vue-js-3-how-to-pass-data-from-one-component-to-another-other)

I'm a little bit confused by this one but then I found

[Passing the data into component in vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62971950/passing-the-data-into-component-in-vuejs)

So I added basically like, a static method

```
<ComponentName prop="something-else" information=information.item1>

methods: {
    information() {
      this.information.item1 = information.item1
    }
},
```

But I get an error about duplicated key and a no-undef error.

How do you pass data from vue into a component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should access directly the data returned from the `data` option and bind it to the prop :

```html
<ComponentName :info="information.item1">
```

Comment: so this doesn't work, I forgot a major detail in the question...I have multiple props on my component. can you still pass data into a prop when you have other props?

Comment: Yes you can do, `<ComponentName :info="information.item1" :info2="information.item2" :info3="information.item3">`

Comment: ok cool, yup I see that now - I didnt have that prop registered

Answer (score 0):

When writing with HTML, you never write `data`, `this`, `methods` or `computed`. You just write the data, method, computed property directly etc.

```
<ComponentName :info=information.item1 />
```

You get an duplicate key error because your method `information` already exist as an property key inside your `data`

With `:` you bind something. Without `:` you just pass an string

I mean, by just looking at the examples you should figure it out that they never use `data` or `this` inside the template

https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html

Comment: so this doesn't work, I forgot a major detail in the question...I have multiple props on my component. can you still pass data into a prop when you have other props?

Comment: @kawnah yes, you can pass as many props as you want

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is register the props.

**For Example.**

The Vue component

`<componentName :lists="lists"></componentName>`

Then in your component register the props

```
props: ['lists'],
data() {
    return {
        information: {
          item1: 'item 1 string',
          item2: 'item 2 string', 
          item3: 'item 3 string'
        } 
    }
}
```

Let me know if this helps you.